# Trying to position multiple repeated elements that are fixed relative to the viewing point

Tags: html, css

My button is described like this

```
<a href="website" class="button">Link 1</a>
```

Now I have another 4 similar buttons to place beside in a horizontal row besides.

```
<a href="website" class="button">Link 2</a>
<a href="website" class="button">Link 3</a>
<a href="website" class="button">Link 4</a>
<a href="website" class="button">Link 5</a>
```

I want `position: fixed;`, as I need those buttons to be on the navigation bar and always present relative to the browser window.

[image]Because of the fixed attribute I can not have `display:inline-block` or `display:inline;`.

I did not want to copy the the button 5 times and each time just change the property of position. I thought I could have a general class which would specify what would be the height from the top of the page for the buttons, and then write in the horizontal shift using

```
<div style="right:10px;">
    <a href="website" style="right: 50px;" class="button">Link 2</a>    
</div>
```

This is does not  work, any containers or attributes added to `div` can not affect the button position even though in it the right distance is not stated.

I know I can do it it by having multiple distinct classes in my CSS for buttons, but they would be exactly the same except for horizontal alignment and this seems like a wasteful way to go about doing so.

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the navbar as a whole (and not the single nav items). In that fixed nav container you can use inline-blocks